# Как прочитать реакцию на сообщение в python боте дискорд

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Пишу бота для дискорд на Python, тут столкнулся с проблемой: не могу понять, как сделать так, чтоб бот понял какую реакцию нажал человек на ОТПРАВЛЕННОМ БОТОМ сообщении и ,исходя из этого, сделал какое-то действие.
Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Ивент установки реакции юзером:

```
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    emoji = payload.emoji # реакция пользователя
```

Ивент удаления реакции пользователем работает также:

```
def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
    emoji = payload.emoji # реакция пользователя
```

Emoji в данном случае может быть кастомным, а также Юникодным

Если вам нужно реагировать на сообщение конкретного пользователя(Бота например), нужно будет добавить данный код:

```
channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id) # Получаем канал
message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)  # Получаем сообщение
author = message.author  # Получаем автора
if author == bot:
    *Ваши действия*
```